# Can <input type="checkbox" > return 0 value?

Tags: html, checkbox, vbscript

I have a  checkbox tablelike this:

```
<html>
<form>
<table width="630" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#999999">
  <tr>
    <td height="30" align="center">x</td>
    <td height="30" align="center">9-10</td>
    <td height="30" align="center">10-11</td>
    <td height="30" align="center">11-12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="30" align="center"> y</td>
    <td height="30" align="center"><input type=checkbox name=composer value=1><br><br></td>
    <td height="30" align="center"><input type=checkbox name=composer value=2><br><br></td>
    <td height="30" align="center"><input type=checkbox name=composer value=3><br><br></td>
  </tr>
</form>
</html>
```

I need to write all checked and unchecked checkbox values to text, but I can't write unchecked checkbox values as zero value to text.

If I select first and third checkbox, it should write `1,0,3` to text but this code writes `1,3`.

```
Dim fso,tst

Set fso=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set tst = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\reading.txt", 2, true)

tst.writeline  Request.Form("composer")

tst.close
Set tst = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. Why do you think you need to export the "value" of an unchecked checkbox as a "0"?

Comment: I have a 3x3 checkboxes table and a 3x3 radioboxes table. If a user checks the first and third checkboxes, first and third radioboxes need to pop up and a text area which includes "full" needed to pop up instead of second radiobox. I use text files to transfer variables between checkboxes and radioboxes table so if first and third checkboxes are selected, the code writes 1,3 to text file, i put them into a array by using split function(vbscript) with deliminator "," but array includes just 1 and 3 not unchecked checkbox whose value is 0.

Comment: Use the `name` attributes for matching checkboxes to radiobuttons. Iterate over the checkboxes and update the radiobuttons with the value of the checkbox only if its `selected` property is `True`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. By definition, a checkbox element contributes to the form data set only when the checkbox is in the checked state. We are supposed to code form data processing so that it takes this into account.

The conclusions depend on the context and goals. If you cannot do things properly server-side, you might use some scripting tricks (which come with risks). On the safer side, you could create checkbox functionality of your own: an element that looks like a checkbox, with client-side scripting code that implements it so that a hidden form field is set to 0 or to some other value, depending on the checkedness state.